# How can I use openmp in android studio

Tags: c++, android-ndk, openmp

I use android-ndk-r10d to code with C++ in android studio. Now I want to use openmp and I add the codes into Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fopenmp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -fopenmp
```

and add the codes into myapp.cpp:

```
#include <omp.h>
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 1, ii = 0; i < outImage[0]->height; i+=2, ii = i>>1) {
 /* Do work... */
}
```

but  gradle build finished with error just because of the [#pragma omp parallel for]
How can I handle the syntax error ?

Comment: can't you use good old `ndk-build`?

Answer (score 1):

May be the compiler does not like the complex structure of the for() statement. OpenMP likes to know the number of steps in advance. Also I doubt that OpenMP can deal with 2 loop variables (i and ii). Try a simple loop with fixed limits like

```
int kmax = (outImage[0]->height - 1) / 2; // not sure this is right

#pragma omp parallel for
for( int k=0; k<kmax; k++)
{
    int i=k*2 + 1; // not sure this is right
    int ii = i>>1;
    /* Do work ... */
}
```